# How to generate Gensis Block in hyperledger fabric without sharing or reveal crypto-config directory each other organization

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

When I am studying the hyperledger fabric blockchain I observe one thing that.
for Network creation in HLF we need to create genesis block which is used by orderer to create system channel and all orderer up.

So I went though the tutorial as
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials.html

I understand that using cryptogen tool or fabric-ca will create crypto-material for all orgs peers, orderers, and Admins. Now When I went to second step where we need to create genesis block using configtxtool with help of configtx.yaml file which contain all network information as below. I found that all we need crypto-config folder in different place like MSP. so in real case one org will not share there cryto-material to each other. so how we can create genesis block in this scenario?

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

---
################################################################################
#
#   Section: Organizations
#
#   - This section defines the different organizational identities which will
#   be referenced later in the configuration.
#
################################################################################
Organizations:

    # SampleOrg defines an MSP using the sampleconfig.  It should never be used
    # in production but may be used as a template for other definitions
    - &OrdererOrg
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: OrdererOrg

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: OrdererMSP

        # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
        MSPDir: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"

        OrdererEndpoints:
            - orderer.example.com:7050

    - &Org1
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: Org1MSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: Org1MSP

        MSPDir: ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.peer', 'Org1MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.peer')"

    - &Org2
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: Org2MSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: Org2MSP

        MSPDir: ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin', 'Org2MSP.peer', 'Org2MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin', 'Org2MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.peer')"

################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Capabilities
#
#   - This section defines the capabilities of fabric network. This is a new
#   concept as of v1.1.0 and should not be utilized in mixed networks with
#   v1.0.x peers and orderers.  Capabilities define features which must be
#   present in a fabric binary for that binary to safely participate in the
#   fabric network.  For instance, if a new MSP type is added, newer binaries
#   might recognize and validate the signatures from this type, while older
#   binaries without this support would be unable to validate those
#   transactions.  This could lead to different versions of the fabric binaries
#   having different world states.  Instead, defining a capability for a channel
#   informs those binaries without this capability that they must cease
#   processing transactions until they have been upgraded.  For v1.0.x if any
#   capabilities are defined (including a map with all capabilities turned off)
#   then the v1.0.x peer will deliberately crash.
#
################################################################################
Capabilities:
    # Channel capabilities apply to both the orderers and the peers and must be
    # supported by both.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        # V2_0 capability ensures that orderers and peers behave according
        # to v2.0 channel capabilities. Orderers and peers from
        # prior releases would behave in an incompatible way, and are therefore
        # not able to participate in channels at v2.0 capability.
        # Prior to enabling V2.0 channel capabilities, ensure that all
        # orderers and peers on a channel are at v2.0.0 or later.
        V2_0: true

    # Orderer capabilities apply only to the orderers, and may be safely
    # used with prior release peers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        # V2_0 orderer capability ensures that orderers behave according
        # to v2.0 orderer capabilities. Orderers from
        # prior releases would behave in an incompatible way, and are therefore
        # not able to participate in channels at v2.0 orderer capability.
        # Prior to enabling V2.0 orderer capabilities, ensure that all
        # orderers on channel are at v2.0.0 or later.
        V2_0: true

    # Application capabilities apply only to the peer network, and may be safely
    # used with prior release orderers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        # V2_0 application capability ensures that peers behave according
        # to v2.0 application capabilities. Peers from
        # prior releases would behave in an incompatible way, and are therefore
        # not able to participate in channels at v2.0 application capability.
        # Prior to enabling V2.0 application capabilities, ensure that all
        # peers on channel are at v2.0.0 or later.
        V2_0: true

################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Application
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for application related parameters
#
################################################################################
Application: &ApplicationDefaults

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the application side of the network
    Organizations:

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Application policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/Application/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        LifecycleEndorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
        Endorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"

    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Orderer
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for orderer related parameters
#
################################################################################
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

    # Orderer Type: The orderer implementation to start
    OrdererType: etcdraft
    # Addresses used to be the list of orderer addresses that clients and peers
    # could connect to.  However, this does not allow clients to associate orderer
    # addresses and orderer organizations which can be useful for things such
    # as TLS validation.  The preferred way to specify orderer addresses is now
    # to include the OrdererEndpoints item in your org definition
    Addresses:
        - orderer.example.com:7050

    EtcdRaft:
        Consenters:
        - Host: orderer.example.com
          Port: 7050
          ClientTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
          ServerTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt

    # Batch Timeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch
    BatchTimeout: 2s

    # Batch Size: Controls the number of messages batched into a block
    BatchSize:

        # Max Message Count: The maximum number of messages to permit in a batch
        MaxMessageCount: 10

        # Absolute Max Bytes: The absolute maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch.
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB

        # Preferred Max Bytes: The preferred maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch. A message larger than the preferred
        # max bytes will result in a batch larger than preferred max bytes.
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the orderer side of the network
    Organizations:

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Orderer policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/Orderer/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        # BlockValidation specifies what signatures must be included in the block
        # from the orderer for the peer to validate it.
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"

################################################################################
#
#   CHANNEL
#
#   This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for channel related parameters.
#
################################################################################
Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Channel policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        # Who may invoke the 'Deliver' API
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        # Who may invoke the 'Broadcast' API
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        # By default, who may modify elements at this config level
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

    # Capabilities describes the channel level capabilities, see the
    # dedicated Capabilities section elsewhere in this file for a full
    # description
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities

################################################################################
#
#   Profile
#
#   - Different configuration profiles may be encoded here to be specified
#   as parameters to the configtxgen tool
#
################################################################################
Profiles:

    TwoOrgsApplicationGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities: *OrdererCapabilities
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
            Capabilities: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the MSPDir:         `MSPDir: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp` only contains public information (CA certificates), and not secret information (private keys) so there is no problem to share that.

What you can do, is have each organization invoke cryptogen on its own, and then have each organization send each other the MSPDir of its own.

Comment: Thanks to explain it I also think same way as its ca certificates so no harm to share those however is there any way to deal with that so we can create genesis block?

Comment: To deal with what?

Answer (score 0):

In a real world application, you wouldn't want to use the Fabric CA or the cryptogen tool provided by Hyperledger Fabric. The reason is pretty obvious and stated in documentation. You should always use OpenSSL or a certificate provided by public CA. (Yes, HLF works without Fabric CA)

The correct way is that all organization should have the msp folder of each organization that will participate in the channel. The msp folder should only include the `../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp` which has the CA or Intermediate CA certificate only (No peer or client cert or key).

Conclusion to your question, in order to generate genesis block at the orderer organization, all the organization you included in the `configtx.yaml` should have their msp available to the orderer organization. (Again, only the CA certificate is enough, you don't need the certificate or the key of the peer or client)